# Find The Sum of This series(Verification)

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

$$ 1+x \cos a +x^2 \cos 2a +x^3 \cos 3a.......$$ up to infinte terms

Below is my attempt. Kindly tell what went wrong.

I assumed this series to be **S** and then multiplied it with $ 2x \cos a$ so that I get

$$ S(2x \cos a)= 2x \cos a+2x^2(\cos a)\cos a +2x^3 \cos 2a \cos a +2x^4(\cos 3a)\cos a \cdots$$

Which becomes $$ S(2x \cos a)=2x \cos a+x^2(\cos 2a+\cos 0)+x^3(\cos 3a+\cos a) \cdots$$

*Now subtracting $S$ from my newly transformed series*(subtracting like coefficients of $x$ )
$$S(2x \cos a-1)=-1+x \cos a +x^2 \cos 0 +x^3\cos a+x^4 \cos 2a \cdots$$

$$S(2x \cos a-1)=-1+x\cos a +x^2\cos 0 +x^2(x \cos a+x^2 \cos 2a \cdots $$
$$S(2x \cos a-1)=-1+x \cos a +x^2 \cos 0 +x^2(-1+1+x \cos a+x^2\cos 2a \cdots $$
$$S(2x \cos a-1)=-1+x \cos a +x^2\cos 0 +x^2(S-1)$$
then on rearrangement this gives
$$S=\frac{(1-x \cos a)}{(x^2-2x \cos a+1)}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Why do you think you got a wrong answer?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Actually this problem was taken from an old book. And the ans to this problem is not given. So I thought that usually on this site Moderators do not allow "check my work" type of thing. So I thought people will come and suggest mistakes if they find any

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thankyou so much for your opinion

Comment: 'Solution verification' is a popular tag on this site. We welcome you to get your proofs verified.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thankyou so much I was unware of this

Comment: @Veerain, could you please explain how did you reach $S(2 \cos a)=2x \cos a+x^2(\cos 2a+\cos 0)+x^3(\cos 3a+\cos a) \cdots$ this step?

Comment: I think I am missing something to understand that.

Comment: @RAHUL I used the identity 2CosACosB =Cos(A+B)+Cos(A-B)

Comment: @Veerain, yaa I got it now. Your proof looks perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I am not able to make a comment. When you find this notice unusefull, I will immediatly delete this post.

Relying to Euler's formula $\cos a+i\cdot\sin a=e^{i\cdot a}$, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20x%5En*cos%28n*a%29%2C%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity) produces for the query `sum x^n*cos(n*a), n=0 to infinity` the following term (I compacted and reduced it a little bit):

$$
2S=\frac{x}{-x+e^{i a}}+\frac{1}{1-e^{i a} x}+1
$$

It would be interesting to know how this relates to the (correct) simplification give in the OP.

Comment: Yes Thank you actually I was hoping for an answer in complex numbers form.

Comment: Great - maybe you can show how it relates to your form.

Comment: Here is the proof brother

Comment: Yes - I see it. Well done!!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the series as following

$$S=1+x\frac{(e^{ia} +e^{-ia})}{2}+x^2\frac{(e^{2ia} +e^{-2ia})}{2}+x^3\frac{(e^{3ia} +e^{-3ia})}{2}............$$
*I can then break the series in 2 parts*

$$S= 1+(\frac{(xe^{ia} )}{2}+\frac{(x^2e^{2ia} )}{2}+\frac{(x^3e^{3ia})}{2}...)+(\frac{(xe^{-ia} )}{2}+\frac{(x^2e^{-2ia} )}{2}+\frac{(x^3e^{-3ia})}{2}...)                                $$
*taking 1/2 common and applying sum to infinte terms of gp considering |x|<1*

$$S=1+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{xe^{ia}}{1-xe^{ia}})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{xe^{-ia}}{1-xe^{-ia}})                                     $$

now for the verification part with wolfram alpha we take multiply 2 on both sides
$$2S=2+(\frac{xe^{ia}}{1-xe^{ia}})+(\frac{xe^{-ia}}{1-xe^{-ia}}) $$
*add 1 to 1st bracket and rearrange 2nd bracket by multiplying neumerator and denominator by $e^{ia}$*
$$2S=1+(\frac{1}{1-xe^{ia}})+(\frac{x}{e^{-ia}-x}) $$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Here is another answer